# Spotify authorization login call in wrong url

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, spotify

I am working on a simple web app to display my currently playing song. I have set up a Spotify account an received a clientId and client secret.
I try to request the initial token, for further communication with the spotify api.

I am displaying the received login html, i try to log in, but nothing happens, it just says "There went something wrong ..." above the login form. At this point i checked the spotify dashboard and whitlisted all the local callback urls, but i am still getting this message an nothing is happening.
I checked the browser dev tools and saw something odd (at least i belive its odd).
The login call redirects to "https://losthost:5001/api/login" which leads to a 404.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Connect()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var clientId = "clientId";

    var redirectUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://localhost:5000/Spotify/Callback/");
    var url = $"client_Id={clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirectUrl}";

    var result = await client.GetAsync($"https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?{url}");

    if (result.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "text/html"){
        var spotifyLoginHtml = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return new ContentResult()
        {
            Content = spotifyLoginHtml,
            ContentType = "text/html",
        };
    }
    else
    {
        //var accessToken = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //return RedirectToAction("DevicesSelection");
    }   

    return View();         
}
```

I think my problem is the wrong login call from the spotify login html, but i dont know why this happens or how to fix it.

Edit:
Added image with initial error (Uncaught in promise) and wrong api/login call
[image: Chrome Dev tool Errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect_uri` :

> The URI to redirect to after the user grants or denies permission. This URI needs to have been entered in the Redirect URI whitelist that you specified when you registered your application. The value of redirect_uri here must exactly match one of the values you entered when you registered your application, including upper or lowercase, terminating slashes, and such.

Spotify provides [article available](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) that covers the authentication and authorization setup and flow step-by-step.

So that if `http://localhost:5000/Spotify/Callback/` is your redirect url , you should firstly add the url to Redirect URI whitelist in dashboard :

[image]

And in your application you should have route matches `http://localhost:5000/Spotify/Callback/` to get the code via query string , and then use code to acquire access token for accessing Spotify  APIs . Here is a code sample :

```
class SpotifyAuthentication
{
    public string clientID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public string clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    public string redirectURL = "https://localhost:44363/callback";
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    SpotifyAuthentication sAuth = new SpotifyAuthentication();

    [HttpGet]
    public ContentResult Get()
    {
        var qb = new QueryBuilder();
        qb.Add("response_type", "code");
        qb.Add("client_id", sAuth.clientID);
        qb.Add("scope", "user-read-private user-read-email");
        qb.Add("redirect_uri", sAuth.redirectURL);

        return new ContentResult
        {
            ContentType = "text/html",
            Content = @"
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta charset=""utf-8"">
                        <title>Spotify Auth Example</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <a href=""https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/" + qb.ToQueryString().ToString() + @"""><button>Authenticate at Spotify</button></a>
                    </body>
                </html>
            "
        };
    }

    [Route("/callback")]
    public ContentResult Get(string code)
    {
        string responseString = "";

        if (code.Length > 0)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Your basic bearer: " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sAuth.clientID + ":" + sAuth.clientSecret)));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sAuth.clientID + ":" + sAuth.clientSecret)));

                FormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", sAuth.redirectURL),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                });

                var response = client.PostAsync("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", formContent).Result;

                var responseContent = response.Content;
                responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }

        return new ContentResult
        {
            ContentType = "application/json",
            Content = responseString
        };
    }
}
```

Code reference : https://github.com/bmsimons/dotnet-core-spotify-authentication and [blog](https://bartsimons.me/net-core-and-the-spotify-api-getting-authenticated/) .

And of course you can use Spotify middleware , [here](https://medium.com/@nbanzyme/setting-up-spotify-authentication-on-asp-net-core-2-2-96356a061f3c) is a code sample .

Comment: Thanks for your response, i tried your code and it works, thank you for that. I think i understand the problem, i cant display the spotify html code in my application, it has to be a link the user clicks, i thougth i can handle the whole login on my site, which seems to be wrong.